# Can I Use an Isolated DC/DC Converter to Step Down a Switching Dynamic Signal?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, switching, level-translation

I have a 24V device that takes a signal of either of 36V or 72V that will switch on and off at around 2Hz. This signal needs to be converted to 24V and I'm considering this [isolated DC/DC converter](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/traco-power/TEN-6-4815WIN/1951-3033-ND/9344555) which can convert 18-75V to 24V. The problem is that I don't know if the device is capable of consistant switching since these are normally used for providing constant power. I looked on the datasheet and it doesn't say anything about switching lifespan or capable number of power-ons. My concerns are about activation time, reduced lifespan, start-up delay, start-up voltage jump, etc.

Is this a viable use of the converter or should I use another device or configuration?

Edit: For clarification, the input signal can come in as either 0V, 36V, or 72V (DC). The output is either 0V and 24V (DC). A 36V and 72V input must translate into a 24V output, and a 0V input must translate to a 0V output.

Comment: I was at one point considering a relay as an alternate solution but couldn't figure out a viable configuration.

Comment: Is the 36/72 V signal a data input to the 24V device? Or is it being stepped down to power it?  If data, how about a resistor and zener diode in series? Would be simpler, cheaper and get the job done.

Comment: If this is important, you need to talk to an application engineer from the company to try to get real numbers, or find a part specced with the factors you need. 

If you want to build a reliable device, and don't care about wasting power, my suggestion would be to seriously overspec your current requirements, and add a substantial constant load.

Comment: @Jim The signal is for data and not power. The signal will go to a component with 2kΩ input resistance. The 24V device is not an digital/logic device.

Comment: So you need to scale down the signal? Since it not digital and therefore analog (presumably?) If it was digital I would have suggested just clamping the signal to 24V with diodes and a series current limiting resistor. If analog, you could use a voltage divider followed by an opamp buffer. You can get opamps up to 140V fairly easily and the opamp in this case doesn't see more than 24V since it sits after the divider

Comment: I don't know if whether to call it digital or analog since I normally consider digital to be 1's and 0's (0V, 5V) and I consider analog to be sine waves, modulated waves, etc. What I mean is that the signal can have one of three states: 0VDC, 36VDC, or 72VDC. 36VDC and 72VDC must be converted to 24VDC and 0VDC stays the same. The 0V/24V signal feeds into a 2kΩ load.

Comment: @IntiEngineer I'd call that analog more than digital, but it is technically multi-level digital. So you can take the opamp scale down approach or use two comparators to dtermine the window the input signal is in, some logic to decide, and simply regenerate the signal at new thresholds. Don't use your original approach. Overblown and underperforming.

Comment: I am a bit confused how input 3 states ends up as only two output states though. Unless everything >=24V is interpreted as the same output in which case it is just binary digital and you can use the clamping diodes and resistor method. There is still vagueness to your question. What input RANGES needs to be mapped to which output, exactly?

Comment: 72V -> 24V,  36V -> 24V,  0V -> 0V. There are no voltages in between.

Comment: @IntiEngineer Definitely just use diode clamps and a series current limiting resistor. 72V and 36V are basically the same as far as the output is concerned. This is a digital system.

Comment: @IntiEngineer You mentioned using an isolated converter. Do you actually need isolation?

Comment: Can you define load or current (mA?)  Can you define noise immunity needs or proximity of noise and cable distance?  Is source earth grounded? or floating?  Is load floating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 24V and 36V inputs are the same output in this system, while a 0V input is still a 0V output. So you just have to clamp the output to 24V. Here are two possible clamping approaches.

The top circuit will clamp at the Vz and all its variation with current.

The bottom circuit will clamp at 24V + Vd.

The resistor size is not critical. It is simply sized to limit the current going through the diode and the current that the output must source. Use the maximum expected input voltage in this calculation, 72V.

In the top circuit, with a 72V input, 48V will appear across the resistor. You can use this to calculate the current.

In the bottom circuit, with a 72V input, 47.3V will appear across the resistor (because the diode forward voltage drop takes up some of the slack).

Note that the bottom does not clamp if the system is not powered. This could fry your input depending on how your system works and is expected to be used. However, the 2K input impedance and R2 may still save your system in this case since it forms a voltage divider. With the shown value of 10K, it steps down 72V to 12V when unpowered.

If you are worried about resistors failing and frying your 24V output then you can use multiple resistors in series to achieve your desired value. If one fails, the others are still there to limit current. Diodes normally fail short which is fine diode failures probably won't fry your input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9bj7E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: In my application, I've also attached an NPN BJT to the output of your Zener circuit. OUT is attached to the base, 24V is connected to the collector, and the 1.2kΩ load is connected to the emitter. This way I can use minimal power from current entering the Zener diode by limiting the current with the 10kΩ resistor. Without the BJT, the circuit requires a current limiting resistor somewhere around 500Ω when the load is connected directly to out in the first circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resistor and a zener in the following configuration (ignore shown voltage levels).

[image]

Image from: https://next-hack.com/index.php/2017/09/15/how-to-interface-a-5v-output-to-a-3-3v-input/

In your case, the zener diode voltage should be 24V. The main drawback using this configuration is that the signal (72V or 36V)must be able to drive some mA to the Zener.

With this configuration, if in your output you have 0V, your input will be 0V. If in your output you have 36V or 72V, your input will be clamped to 24V.

Answer (score 0):

If you could benefit from isolation, another option is to use an [SSR](http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/CPC1017N.pdf/$file/CPC1017N.pdf) plus an input resistor.

[image]

This one is recommended to have 3mA drive so a resistor of about 10K on the input would be about right for 30-77V. The switching time is less than 10ms, so acceptable for 2Hz.

DC-DC converters might work okay, or they might not. I have seen them take a good fraction of a second to fully start so that would be unacceptable in your application. They will also have an output capacitor that will need a load to discharge it within a reasonable length of time.